# Google Sheets | Count items grouped by type

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, formula, vlookup

I have a google sheet/workbook; within sheet 1 I have the following data.
Example Set:

```
ColA        | ColB
10-27 10:00 | A
10-27 10:00 | A
10-27 10:00 | B
10-27 10:00 | A
10-27 10:00 | B
10-27 10:01 | A
10-27 10:01 | A
...
10-27 10:20 | B
10-27 10:20 | A
10-27 10:20 | B
```

I would like to output the transformed data to a separate sheet.
Desired Output:

```
Time        | ACount | BCount
10-27 10:00 | 3      | 2
10-27 10:01 | 2      | 0
...
10-27 10:20 | 1      | 2
```

Alternatively, if someone knows how to make a stacked bar graph from the example data without transforming it, that would also be useful to understand.

I have tried all sorts of things with no luck: query, countif, vlookup

Any help, or links would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Could you show your query, which didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivot table to count values:

[image]

Comment: So easy, and neat answer. Should really be the accepted answer. :/

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Assuming your existing sheet is called Sheet1 (update Sheet1 references if sheet name is different).

Put your headers in Row 1 of Sheet 2.

For `A2` of Sheet2:

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)
```

For `B2` of Sheet2 (fill down through rows as needed):

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=$A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B="A"))
```

For `C2` of Sheet2:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=$A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B="B"))
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me the total count of A's and B's rather than the individual counts.

Comment: Ah, needed one more filter in each. Try this for the A column 

=COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:B,Sheet1!$A$2:A=A2,Sheet1!$B$2:B="A"))

And for the B column:

=COUNTA(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:B,Sheet1!$A$2:A=A2,Sheet1!$B$2:B="B"))